# How to sign an XFA PDF signature field?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, sign, xfa

I have an XFA-PDF created with Adobe Live Cycle. The PDF has 2 signature fields. Each field has to be signed through code by a Windows service at different times.
Is there a way to accomplish this using iTextSharp or another API?
Thank you for taking time to read and help.

I followed sample code and was able to sign the entire PDF file using iTextSharp, however, this doesn't sign any of the actual fields. 
If it is possible to use iTextSharp, can someone please help me by showing how to specify which field to sign?

This is the code I use to sign the file:

```cs
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
FileOutputStream os = new  FileOutputStream(dest);
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createXmlSignature(reader, os);
XmlSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getXmlSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setXmlLocator(new XfaXmlLocator(stamper));
appearance.setXpathConstructor(new XfaXpathConstructor(XfaXpathConstructor.XdpPackage.Datasets));
ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, "BC");
MakeXmlSignature.signXmlDSig(appearance, signature, chain);
```

But I want to sign the XFA Signature fields

Comment: As far as I can see the iText support for XML signatures is essentially merely a proof of concept and does not offer to sign specific existing fields. Considering XFA support in PDFs has been deprecated with ISO 32000-2, I wouldn't count on this feature to be developed any further soon.

Comment: #mkl. Thanks for letting me know. I'm not very familiar with XFA, but this helped me figure out where to go next to get more information.